# Drupal 7 Views PHP module echo taxonomy term

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I'm using the Views PHP module with the following code:

```
<?php
  echo $row->title;
  echo $row->field_home_away_or_neutral;
  echo $row->field_team;
  echo $row->field_opponent;
  echo $row->field_goals_scored;
  echo $row->field_goals_conceded;
?>
```

This prints the title correctly but all other variables are returned the same number per row e.g. 17 17 17 17 17 then 15 15 15 15 15

These fields are taxonomy terms and integers.

How do I print the actual values e.g. $row->field_home_away_or_neutral would be either 'Home', ' Away' or 'Neutral'?

Available variables:

$view: The view object.

$handler: The handler object.

$static: A variable that can be used to store reusable data per row.

$row: Contains the retrieved record from the database (e.g. $data->nid).

$row->title: Content: Title

$row->field_home_away_or_neutral: Field: Home, Away or Neutral

$row->field_team: Field: Team

$row->field_opponent: Field: Opponent

$row->field_goals_scored: Field: Goals scored

$row->field_goals_conceded: Field: Goals conceded

$row->path: Content: Path

$row->php: Global: PHP

$data: Contains the retrieved record from the database (e.g. $data->nid).

$value: Value of this field.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in Views PHP (see http://drupal.org/node/1140896)

You can get to the values using:

```
$data->field_field_home_away_or_neutral[0]['rendered']['#markup'];
```

... where _field_home... is the field you want to target.

Use the Devel module and

```
dsm($data);
```

to build the correct 'path' to the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to get the term name:

```
// In your case the $tid is $row->field_home_away_or_neutral;
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
echo $term->name;
```

Let us know if it works for you!

Comment: Interesting, used the following: `$term = taxonomy_term_load($row->field_home_away_or_neutral);
print 'Result:' . $term->name;` but got the Title field value returned instead? I've added a list of available variables in my original post. Been playing around and have a feeling it is the $data or $value vars that will return the result?

Comment: Oops, my bad.  That should say echo $term->name;  Otherwise it doesn't actually print anything out!!  Try that.  I just tested it and it definitely works!!  I just edited my response to reflect that change.

Comment: No, that doesn't work but it turns out it is a bug with Views PHP (http://drupal.org/node/1140896). You can get the values using `$data->field_field_home_away_or_neutral[0]['rendered']['#markup'];`. Many thanks for trying to help me out though :-)

Comment: Ah ok.  I was testing the php out NOT via a view.